# Are Shopify Apps that ask new permissions safe?

Tags: shopify

I have a small business and I am planning to create a store on shopify. A friend of mine used to own a business which he later on shutdown. He advised that I need to be careful about the apps I choose to install on my store, and understand what permissions I am approving for the app and whether each permission is really required to provide the custom functionality I need. He specifically talked about permissions like read_all_orders and read_orders because they look similar but are different*.* How hard is it to evaluate permissions for each app I want to install?

Also can apps ask for new permissions after I install? If you're a merchant, did you find such apps safe to use?

Lastly, I thought it will be great if they can verify if a certain kind of scope is required for the feature app will offer, and not allow apps to randomly ask for new scopes after installation.

Am I being too paranoid about apps?

Comment: Yes, need to aware of the permissions that the apps are asked for while you install them to the Shopify store, most of the APPS are created by professionals, and they also aware of data security and try to meet the height end acceptance.

Comment: Sometimes some APP gathers some extra data for their new APP or analytic purpose, you can ask them regarding it via email, live chat, or support also. It is solely on you if you want a particular functionality that suits and can grow you into digital space. it is totally on you go with them for not.